# XNA ContentLoadException from array given by Directory.GetFiles when file is clearly there

Tags: xna, loading, spritefont

First I would like to state that this is not a Content.RootDirectory = "Content"; problem. I've tried this with and without that line of code. I have a class called FileFactory that has three dictionaries. One for textures, one for sounds, and one for sprite fonts. I also have other factories that load in XML files for other types of objects and those work perfectly. Here's the code that loads the fonts:

```
        public static void LoadFonts(ContentManager content)
    {
        string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"Content\fonts\");
        string key;

        foreach (string s in filePaths)
        {
            key = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(s);
            Fonts.Add(key, content.Load<SpriteFont>(s));
        }
    }
```

The error it gives is: "Error loading "Content\fonts\ammoFont.xnb". File not found." even though the file is CLEARLY there considering it would have to be in the directory to be added to the filePaths array as a string. I've even checked the folder and it is there. Here is the full error:

> Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentLoadException was unhandled
>   Message=Error loading "Content\fonts\ammoFont.xnb". File not found.
>   Source=Microsoft.Xna.Framework   StackTrace:
>          at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.OpenStream(String
>   assetName)
>          at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.ReadAsset[T](String
>   assetName, Action`1 recordDisposableObject)
>          at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.Load[T](String
>   assetName)
>          at OfUnknownOrigin.FileFactory.LoadFonts(ContentManager content) in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\FileFactory.cs:line
>   38
>          at WindowsGame1.UnknownOrigin.LoadContent() in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\Game.cs:line 110
>          at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Initialize()
>          at WindowsGame1.UnknownOrigin.Initialize() in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\Game.cs:line 102
>          at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.RunGame(Boolean useBlockingRun)
>          at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
>          at WindowsGame1.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Chris\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2010\Projects\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\WindowsGame1\Program.cs:line
>   15   InnerException: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>          Message=Error loading "Content\Content\fonts\ammoFont.xnb.xnb". File not found.
>          Source=Microsoft.Xna.Framework
>          StackTrace:
>               at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.TitleContainer.OpenStream(String name)
>               at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content.ContentManager.OpenStream(String
>   assetName)
>          InnerException:

Answer:
Change this code:

```
Fonts.Add(key, content.Load<SpriteFont>(s));
```

to this:

```
Fonts.Add(key, content.Load<SpriteFont>("fonts\\" + key));
```

Comment: As a test, does `Content.Load<SpriteFont>("fonts/ammoFont");` work by itself outside of your `LoadFonts()` method?

Comment: Yes, that does work. That is how I was doing it before I created the FileFactory class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the exception message, it looks like the string you are calling it with is wrong. Content is in there twice, and the extension is there twice:

```
Error loading "Content\Content\fonts\ammoFont.xnb.xnb"
```

You didnt post the code where you initialize the array, but if you have them in the definition, remove them.

Comment: Here is the Dictionary for the fonts being initialized:
`public static Dictionary<string, SpriteFont> Fonts = new Dictionary<string, SpriteFont>();`
I can't figure out why Content and the extension are there twice.

Comment: Try `Fonts.Add(key, content.Load<SpriteFont>("fonts\\" + key));`

Comment: Ok, that seems to have worked. I'm not exactly sure why though. Thank you!

Comment: Its because `Directory.GetFiles(@"Content\fonts\");` gives you back the _full_ file path including the extension, so in this case `Content\fonts\ammoFont.xnb`. Load<SpriteFont> is expecting just the path from root and the file name, and preppends the root directory (`Content\`) and appends the expected extension (`.xnb`). You already got just the file name it wants in your `key` definition, so you can just feed Load<SpriteFont> the directory name (`fonts\`) and the file name (`key`) and it does the rest for you.

Comment: Yeah, after examining the code more I realized that. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Game content paths must be relative to your `Content.RootFolder` ("Content\" by default) and must not contain file extension (so avoid duplicate file names, even if the extensions are different).

Comment: The paths are relative to that. I've tried this with and without setting a Content.RootFolder and the same thing happens. The path for Directory.GetFiles is not relative to the Content.RootFolder though. I've fiddled with the code and string layout to no avail.

Comment: You include file extensions in your paths, you must remove those extensions.

Comment: Look at the code above. I haven't added any file extensions into the paths.

Comment: @Bagofsheep I quote your question: `The error it gives is: "Error loading "Content\fonts\ammoFont.xnb". File not found."`